# How to combine two rtp streams

Tags: byte, rtp, voice

I have two byte arrays full of raw data from RTP packets.
Each array is representing a voice and one person in the conversion, and I would like to put them together so I can hear the whole conversion. 
The two arrays are pretty much the same size.

I hread that maybe I need to create a third array and each byte there should be the sum of the bytes in the same locations in the two arrays - C[i]=A[i]+B[i].

I think it needs to be some operation between the two arrays.

any ideas?
Thnaks ahead

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix both the **RTP** streams together. You have keep it separate, and convert each to .wav or mp3 format then mix it. You can write each array to separate files.